# Where to find Connection Point name to access FileNet Process Engine

Tags: filenet-process-engine, filenet-cpe

I am trying to connect to IBM FileNet Process Engine. Unfortunately I am lost where to find where I can get Connection Point name needed to connect.

Answer (score 0):

To find the connection point, go to Process Designer and Click View and Configuration. Connection point is located on the left side of the screen.